# search for '-' in Azure Search query

Tags: json, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Search and I want to search for this specific word with the dash in between:

> Top-Light

My json post body is:

```
{
    "search":"/(.*)top-light(.*)/",
    "queryType":"full",
    "top":1000
}
```

The result is empty because he replaces the "-" with empty "". so he is trying to search for toplight which does not exist.

I tried the escape character:

> "search":"/(.*)top-light(.*)/"

and I received an error:

> The request is invalid. Details: parameters : Invalid JSON. An unrecognized escape sequence '\-' was found in a JSON string value.

I tried to use:

- \-
- (-)
- (-*)
- (.*)
- \\-
- /-

and none of them works. Any suggestion?

thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Just filter it as a string. [search.ismatch('"top-light"', '[whatever the field is]').

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with my question. I am talking about Azure search